# Xcode 4.2 and git - unabled commit

Tags: xcode, git

I have a git repository - including different tech. Android and iPhone.
The folder is like this:

```
.git
Android
iPhone
```

I take that it is possible to have this scenario - that is, having eclipse handle Android and Xcode handle iPhone.

Eclipse(Egit) has no problem working with this, Xcode on the other hand is unable to work with this?

I do have setup the reprository in the Organizer allright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode need the .git in the project folder in your case iPhone. If you want to keep this project structure. Then there is only one solution. Fire up your terminal and type git commands manually.